# Is my client considered public/confidential if I send the secret to the BE through UI

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

We have an app (A) where we register oauth client(s) and we get the usual clientId and clientSecret in return. And we have another app (B) which will call service A with oauth. Both A & B are web-apps with backend and frontend channel. The actual oauth communication will be made by B's backend. What we don't know, if we can create a view in B's UI where the clientID and clientSecret could be configured for B's backend and that we can then think about B as a confidential or public client?! I mean, once we somehow configure and send the secret to B it can keep it secret except that we had to create a view in an SPA to configure it. Does that make the client public?

Both apps are installed on-premise, so ahead of time configuration of the secret in B is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I belive if you're exposing the client secret and client id on the frontend, then it's a public client.

> public
> Clients incapable of maintaining the confidentiality of their
> credentials (e.g., clients executing on the device used by the
> resource owner, such as an installed native application or a web
> browser-based application), and incapable of secure client
> authentication via any other means.

Your UI cannot guarantee the confidentiality of the client's credentials.